# Kana keyboard layout on Android/GBoard

Tags: support

I've found out how to switch between QWERTY and keitai-style flick keyboard for Japanese input on Android, but I'd like to have a kana layout similar to PC and Mac:
[image: kana layout]
Is it possible with Google's standard keyboard (GBoard), or do I need a third-party keyboard app?

Comment: Cross-posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208790/japanese-kana-screen-keyboard-layout